# Real Analysis: close sets and limit point examples

Tags: real-analysis

For the following example:(if possible give example or just state impossible

1) a bounded subset A of R for which sup A is not a limit point of A. An example is (0,1) union {7}. will this work?

2) a finite subset A of R that is not closed
I think it is not possible. Please give some hints if you think there is an answer

Comment: What do you mean by $(0,1) \cup (7)$?

Comment: I tried to find a subset that in between 0 and 1 and have one extra point at 7 to show that 7 is not a limit point of A

Comment: I really mean (0,1) union {7}.

Answer (score 1):

Under the usual topology every finite subset of $\Bbb{R}$ is closed.  Simply make open intervals $(a,b)$ between each two consecutive points $a,b$ in the list.  And make open rays $(a, \pm\infty)$ at the ends of the list $a$.  The union of these open sets is again open, by definition, so you have that the complement of any finite set in $\Bbb{R}$ is open, or equivalently that any finite set is closed.